# receiving the data from multiple ip address using udp communication in c# window form application

Tags: c#

Well, I wonder if some one can help me with a problem that I encounter....

I am not able to receive data from multiple ip address using udp communication.

I can receive data continuously from the same ip address.

what should i do to receive continuous data from different ip address .

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Threading;


  namespace socket_udp_ipv4_server
  {

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.162.2.10");
    int MyPort = 80;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Client = new UdpClient(MyPort);          
        Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), null);

    }
    private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, MyPort);
        byte[] data;
        try
        {
          data = Client.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);

            if (data.Length == 0)
               return; // No more to receive

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return; // Connection closed
        }

        // Send the data to the UI thread
        this.BeginInvoke((Action<IPEndPoint, string>)DataReceivedUI, ip, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), null);
    }

    private void DataReceivedUI(IPEndPoint endPoint, string data)
    {


        textBox1.AppendText(("[" + endPoint.ToString() + "] "+data + Environment.NewLine));

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the machines have route among them? Are the ports open? Is this lan or wan?

Comment: You need a begin Accept.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.100).aspx.  You can replace sockets in sample code with any class that inherits the socket like UdpClient.  The UdpClient has a property Client which is the socket in the example.

Comment: Machines have route among them and the ports are open.Its lan connection.